# Is possible to use Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with SSL (HTTPS) without a Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

From now on, my application needs a secure connection (HTTPS). I verify that most of tutorials for adding secure connections (https) on Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk uses the Elastic Load Balancer as a tunnel.

In my case I'm running a single instance, in fact I don't need a Load Balancer. How can I add a secure connection to my instance without a Elastic Load Balancer? Is that possible?

I am using 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.4.4 running PHP 7.0 Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is definitely possible. Here is an [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html) from AWS using Apache.

The basic steps are:

1. Enable SSL on the server
2. Get a certificate authority (CA) signed certificate. For testing purposes you can create a self signed cert. Here is an [example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self) of how to do that using openssl.

Comment: please verify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310436/how-to-configure-ssl-in-a-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-instance-with-configuration-f

Comment: Smauel Neff's answer is correct. It is certainly AWS best practice when using a managed resource like Beanstalk to also use also use a managed service like ELB to handle SSL encryption. But, it is possible to not follow that practice and manage it yourself. Just adds more configuration for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

You can also use CloudFront for this. This will also allow you to use certification from Certification Manager. Just remember to create them in N-Virginia region.

**WARNING**

The data between `CloudFront` and `Elastic Beanstalk` is still going to be exchanged over `http` as your container doesn't support `https`.
[image]

You also need to change the following settings:

- Under **Allowed HTTP Methods** you need to selected at least `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS`, but most likely you'll want also POST/PUT
  [image: allowed http methods]
- You don't want CloudFront to cache your results, so you'll need to set the `Cache Policy` to **Managed-CachingDisabled**
  [image]
- You also want your all the request's headers, cookies & query strings to be passed on to the `Origin` i.e. your `Elastic BeanStalk Container`. To do so you need to set the `Origin Request Policy` to **Managed-AllViewer**
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

`https` can be configured without a load balancer using a proxy server which is your case (php with Amazon Linux 2+) should be `nginx`. I have created a [`gist` for configuring `https` in EBS](https://gist.github.com/Guneetgstar/4daae13081fb72a62eba5538e22a8cb0) and it fits in Free Tier   but for java. You can see more [examples here](https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/tree/main/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-instancecert) but first find what proxy server you are using(apache or nginx) as the configuration varies accordingly. For more info see [Reverse proxy configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

Answer (score -1):

Currently aws docs are for old amazon linux, so they won't work.

Here's what you should do:

1. Open port 443 in security groups
2. Add your certificate and private key files on the server. You can use .ebextensions for that.
3. Create nginx conf file on the server in /etc/nginx/conf.d, and make it listen to port 443 and use your certificate files to encrypt connection.

In proxy_pass add your app (127.0.0.1:your_port)

You can either create nginx conf files using ssh or add .platform/nginx/conf.d in your app's root folder and add your configuration files in there.

If you prefer more detailed explanation, here you go:
https://youtu.be/zTXS3a67-9c

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28460466)

Comment: @legoscia thanks for advice, I changed it.