# How to configure SSL in a Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Instance with configuration files and without a Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to provide a configuration file in `.ebextension/` folder that would allow my EC2 Elastic Beanstalk instance to reply HTTPS.

I am using 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.4.4 running PHP 7.0 Elastic Beanstalk.

How can I configure my server to enable HTTPS using configuration files?

Comment: You should look up tutorials for using Let's Encrypt on Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Have you solved this. I have managed to setup nginx with a cert on the single instance but all https calls get dropped. they do not even reach nginx

Answer (score -2):

Don't try to fight AWS best practices. To use HTTPS with Elastic Beanstalk configure the certificate in AWS Certificate Manager and assign it to Elastic Beanstalk's load balancer.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

Comment: I understand. however my question is how to it without Load Balancer.

Comment: @DanielSantos why? it's kinda like saying I want to screw in some screws with a hammer.. why? use the right tool for the job. or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid ELB monthly costs.

Comment: @DanielSantos oh, ELB costs are pretty low, I'd never considered them. Good luck and thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @DanielSantos I don't understand why this is marked as accepted when the answer only provides a solution involving a load balancer.

Comment: you're right. for me the advice to 'does not fight best practices" was enough. But some users want to seek the same question/answer.